# Synchronous http call in angularJs inside a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Have a scenario where data is being read from an array, and for each entry, there are 3 tables updated, for which I have nested the HTTP request so all the transaction are sequential. But the problem comes when the loop traverses to the next index immediately without the earlier HTTP promises being resolved. 
At the server end, there is an SQLite DB being used which do not allow parallel write request, so all the subsequent loop iteration is being rejected. Is there a way I can make the particular loop iteration wait until all the promises get resolved?

```
angular.forEach($scope.array, function(arrayEntry){


$http.post('url1', arrayEntry.data1).then(function(response){
    $http.post('url2', arrayEntry.data2).then(function(response){
        $http.post('url3', arrayEntry.data3).then(function(response){
            console.log('data updated');
        })
    })
})

});
```

Comment: if you have `$http` calls in a loop, it's best to adopt a `$q.all`, which will resolve all promises (in an array). Just append your promises into a single array and pass it as: `$q.all(promises).then(/*"in sync now"*/)`

Comment: But the problem with this logic as well, how can I make the next iteration of the loop to wait for the promise to resolve? I tried adding some $timeout, to put some delay but that too did not work out.

Comment: that's the issue, that it's asynchronous. The data may arrive in a few milliseconds, or in an hour. You can't _just wait_ for it

Comment: You can do it by properly chaining them all one after another, see my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

Angular **doesn't and will not** support synchronous http call.

Having said that, no one is stopping you from creating your own XHR request, you'd just need to be aware of all the silly cross-browser quirks that come with XHR. [[ 1 ]](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2391#issuecomment-40420378)

You might want to read the discussion on it here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2391

For your own XHR request here is an example

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do async calls in sequence with help of promise library `q`. In angular it is injectable as `$q` or can be found on $rootScope.

For executing in sequence (not parallel) you can do the following:

```
const dataArray = $scope.array;
const promises = dataArray.reduce((asyncOp, elem) => {
    return asyncOP.then($http.post('url1', elem.data1))
              .then($http.post('url2', elem.data2))
              .then($http.post('url3', elem.data3))
}, $q.when());

promises.then((resp) => console.log('All ops done'));
```

But I would recommend if you do parallel calls as sequential calls are too much time consuming.

Comment: How will the 2nd parameter of reduce function will work here? Will this restrict the iteration till promise is resolved or the loop will continue to check the promise condition and execute the function once promise is resolved?

Comment: The 2nd parameter is just the accumulator, the loop never waits for the promise to be complete. The only function of loop here is to chain all the promise to the 2nd parameter .i.e `$q.when()`. The whole query becomes something like `$q.when().then(asyncOperation1).then(asyncOperation2) ...` and so on. Thus all are in sequence.

Comment: I tried the similar logic in a different approach, but the problem is the system is getting too much busy in the loop that it's not even listening to the promise, and in the end, system is getting crashed

Comment: The idea here is never to stop the loop. Loop is there to build a chained async query. Did you try the above function?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
 function httpCall(arrayEntry) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    //setTimeout(defer.resolve, arrayEntry*1000);
    $http.post('url1', arrayEntry.data1)
        .then(()=> $http.post('url2', arrayEntry.data2))
        .then(()=> $http.post('url3', arrayEntry.data3))
        .then((lastresult)=> defer.resolve(lastresult))
        .catch((err)=> defer.reject(err));
    return defer.promise;
}

// you can remove this
function myfunction(item) {
  return function() {
    return httpCall(item).then(function () {
      console.log(item);
    });
  };
}

//var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
data = $scope.array;
var chain = $q.when();
data.forEach(function (item) {
  chain = chain.then(myfunction(item));
});
return chain;
```

Comment: This logic looks good to me as well, but did not worked out. The loop did not waited for the promise to resolve. Only change i did was to use angular foreach statement.

Comment: chain.then(()=>{}) It'll wait until everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up in using a kind of recursive loop which works well for this scenario. 
The loop may or may not run in recursive flow, but will definitely chain all the promises.

```
// deep copy array
angular.forEach($scope.array, function(arrayEntry){
    $scope.tempArray.push(arrayEntry);
});

if($scope.tempArray.length > 0){
    loop($scope.tempArray.pop());
}

function loop(arrayEntry){
    $http.post('url1', arrayEntry.data1).then(function(response){
        $http.post('url2', arrayEntry.data2).then(function(response){
            $http.post('url3', arrayEntry.data3).then(function(response){
                if($scope.tempArray.length > 0){
                    loop($scope.tempArray.pop());
                }else{
                    window.alert('saved');
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code, it is work for me. I have count length array and after complete loop then execute synchronous code

```
var j=1
  angular.forEach(yourarrayofdata,function (instrumentId){
  $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: "https://yoururl.com"+instrumentId,
         headers: headers1
       }).then(function(response) {
         if(response.data.status=="Ok"){
              instrumentdata=response.data.instrument
              $scope.productdata1[key]=response.data1;
              $scope.productdata2[key]=response.data2;
              if(j==yourarrayofdata.length){
                 //ENTER synchronous CODE HERE
              }
              j++
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seems like it will synchronize every iteration of the forEach loop. The problem here was to synchronize every iteration of the loop so that data gets updates sequentially